# Changing the string values in a column Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, filter

I have a pandas csv file down below. In the `symbol` column I want to replace all the `BTC/USD` plots to `BTCUSD`. How would I be able to do that?

Code:

```
# read_csv function which is used to read the required CSV file
data = pd.read_csv("sample.txt")
```

csv file:

```
unix,date,symbol,open,high,low,close,Volume BTC
1544217600,2018-12-07 21:20:00,BTC/USD,3348.77,3350.41,3345.07,3345.12,3.11919918
1544217540,2018-12-07 21:19:00,BTC/USD,3342.24,3351.14,3342.24,3346.37,21.11950697
1544217480,2018-12-07 21:18:00,BTC/USD,3336.02,3336.02,3336.02,3336.02,0.0
1544217420,2018-12-07 21:17:00,BTC/USD,3332.26,3336.02,3330.69,3336.02,3.28495056
```

Expected Output:

```
unix,date,symbol,open,high,low,close,Volume BTC
1544217600,2018-12-07 21:20:00,BTCUSD,3348.77,3350.41,3345.07,3345.12,3.11919918
1544217540,2018-12-07 21:19:00,BTCUSD,3342.24,3351.14,3342.24,3346.37,21.11950697
1544217480,2018-12-07 21:18:00,BTCUSD,3336.02,3336.02,3336.02,3336.02,0.0
1544217420,2018-12-07 21:17:00,BTCUSD,3332.26,3336.02,3330.69,3336.02,3.28495056
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `str.replace` like this:

```
df['symbol'] = df['symbol'].str.replace('BTC/USD','BTCUSD')
```

Comment: Instead of replacing `BTC/USD` why don't just replace `/`?

Comment: You can also do that. I hust did it like that so he can better understand how it works :)

Answer (score -1):

```py
     # importing pandas module 
     import pandas as pd
  
     # reading csv file 
     data = pd.read_csv("sample.txt")
  
     # overwriting column with replaced value
     data["Team"]= data["symbol"].str.replace("BTC/USD", "BTCUSD", case = False)
```